# my run-length encoding doesn't work with big numbers

Tags: c++

I have a assingment were I need to code and decode txt files, for example: hello how are you? has to be coded as hel2o how are you? and aaaaaaaaaajkle as a10jkle.

```
while ( ! invoer.eof ( ) ) {
        if (kar >= '0' && kar <= '9') {
            counter = kar-48;
            while (counter > 1){
                uitvoer.put(vorigeKar);
                counter--;
            }

        }else if (kar == '/'){
            kar = invoer.get();
            uitvoer.put(kar);
        }else{
            uitvoer.put(kar);
        }
            vorigeKar = kar;

        kar = invoer.get ( );
    }
```

but the problem I have is if need to decode a12bhr, the answer is aaaaaaaaaaaabhr but I can't seem to get the 12 as number without problems, I also can't use any strings or array's.

c++

Comment: *I also can't use any strings* -- What is `kar`?  What is the significance of testing for `/`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: my variable name, it's the char that a take from a txt document, the check of / is part of my assignment for school,

Comment: I know it's a variable.  The issue is that we have no idea the source of where these characters are coming from, since you say you can't use strings.  Also, just because you can't use strings doesn't mean you can't apply the same principle you would use if you could use strings.  How would you convert `"123"` into 123, character-by-character?

Comment: we get a txt, file from our teacher, char by char we need to take it from the file and run the decoding program.

Comment: So again, how do you convert `"123"` into 123 if you got `1`, then `2`, then `3`?  Do you know the basic principle behind how to do that?  It doesn't matter where the characters came from, whether it is a file, or a string being processed in a loop a character at a time.

Comment: You need to keep eating digits until there are no more, while your current code assumes there is only a single digit. You can use `invoer.peek()` to look at the next character without eating it.

Comment: ok, i guess I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, that's one of the issues you have to solve.  If you can't turn, say `"17"` into `17` when you see `'1'` and then `'7'`, then that is a major issue as to why you can't complete the program, strings or no strings.  If you searched for "turn string into number", even though you are not using strings, you will see the principle behind how this is done.  It involves multiplying a total by 10 for each digit character encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are making following mistake: imagine you give `a32`, then you read the character `a` and save it as `vorigeKar` (previous character, I am , Flemish so I understand Dutch :-) ).
Then you read `3`, you understand that it is a number and you repeat `vorigeKar` three times, which leads to `aaa`. Then you read `2` and repeat `vorigeKar` two times, leading to `aaaaa` (five times, five equals 3 + 2).

You need to learn how to keep on reading numeric characters, and translate them into complete numbers (like 32, or 12 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dominique said in his answers, You're doing it wrong.

Let me tell you my logic, you can try it.

**Pesudo Code + Logic:**

```
 Store word as a char array or string, so that it'll be easy to print at last 
    Loop{
    Read - a //check if it's number by subtracting from '0'
    Read - 1 //check if number = true. Store it in int res[] = res*10 + 1
    //Also store the previous index  in an index array(ie) index of char 'a' if you encounter a number first time.
    Read - 2 //check if number = true. Store it in res = res*10 + 2
    Read - b , h and so on till "space" character 

    If you encounter another number, then store it's previous character's index in index array and then store the number in a res[] array.
    Now using index array you can get the index of your repeating character to be printed and print it for it's corresponding times which we have stored in the result array. 
    This goes for the second, third...etc:- numbers in your word till the end of the word
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, even though you say you can't use strings, you still need to know the basic principle behind how to turn a stream of digit characters into an integer.

Assuming the number is positive, here is a simple function that turns a series of digits into a number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int runningTotal(char ch, int lastNum)
{
  return lastNum * 10 + (ch -'0');
}

int main()
{
   // As a test
   char s[] = "a123b23cd1/";
   
   int totalNumber = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '/'; ++i)
   {
      char digit = s[i];  // This is the character "read from the file"
      if ( isdigit( digit) )
          totalNumber = runningTotal(digit, totalNumber);
       else
       {
          if ( totalNumber > 0 )
              std::cout << totalNumber << "\n";
          totalNumber = 0;
       }
   }
   std::cout << totalNumber;
}
```

Output:

```
123
23
1
```

So what was done?  The character array is the "file".  I then loop for each character, building up the number.  The `runningTotal` is a function that builds the integer from each digit character encountered.  When a non-digit is found, we output that number and start the total from 0 again.

The code does not save the letter to "multiply" -- I leave that to you as homework.  But the code above illustrates how to take digits and create the number from them.  For using a file, you would simply replace the `for` loop with the reading of each character from the file.